# Symfony2 ClassNotFoundException

Tags: php, symfony, classnotfoundexception

I included a set of helper classes under a directory called Model, inside a Bundle.

This is how the main directory looks like:

```
OfflineAnalyticsDev
    Source Files
        /app
        /bin
        /app
        /src
            ...
            /OfflineAnalytics
                /OfflineAnalyticsBundle
                    /Controller
                    /DependencyInjection
                    /Model
                        ...
                        SugarCrmConnect.php
                    /Resources
                    /Tests
                    ...
                OfflineAnalyticsOfflineAnalyticsBundle.php
        /vendor
        /web
```

Inside SugarCrmConnect.php I have a class called SugarCrmConnect

```
    namespace OfflineAnalytics\OfflineAnalyticsBundle\Model;

    class SugarCrmConnect
    {
        public static $urlSuffix = "service/v4/soap.php?wsdl";
        public static function login($crmHost, $username, $password)
        {
...
```

I am trying to call the Login method from my DefaultController, but it always shows a ClassNotFoundException. I am even calling other classes from the Model directory/namespace which do work, but this one specifically doesn't.

```
namespace OfflineAnalytics\OfflineAnalyticsBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use OfflineAnalytics\OfflineAnalyticsBundle\Model\GoogleAnalyticsHit;
use OfflineAnalytics\OfflineAnalyticsBundle\Model\GoogleAnalyticsUploadService;
use OfflineAnalytics\OfflineAnalyticsBundle\Model\SugarCrmConnect;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $response = new Response();
        $hit = new GoogleAnalyticsHit('*******', '******','***', '***','**', '***');
        GoogleAnalyticsUploadService::uploadHit($hit);

        $loginResult = SugarCrmConnect::login("************", "***",     "***");
        return $response->setContent('<html><body><h1>'.$loginResult['id'].'</h1></body>    </html>');
    }
}
```

I have tried changing the filename to match the classname and everything, but it still doesn't work.

Here is the full error message:

```
Attempted to load class "SugarCrmConnect" from namespace "OfflineAnalytics\OfflineAnalyticsBundle\Model" 
in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\OfflineAnalyticsDev\src\OfflineAnalytics\OfflineAnalyticsBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php line 19. 
Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?

INFO - Matched route "offline_analytics_offline_analytics_homepage" (parameters: "_controller": "OfflineAnalytics\OfflineAnalyticsBundle\Controller\DefaultController::indexAction", "_route": "offline_analytics_offline_analytics_homepage") 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\SecurityListener::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController". 
EMERGENCY - Class 'OfflineAnalytics\OfflineAnalyticsBundle\Model\SugarCrmConnect' not found 
CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: "Attempted to load class "SugarCrmConnect" from namespace "OfflineAnalytics\OfflineAnalyticsBundle\Model" in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\OfflineAnalyticsDev\src\OfflineAnalytics\OfflineAnalyticsBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php line 19. Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?" at C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\OfflineAnalyticsDev\src\OfflineAnalytics\OfflineAnalyticsBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php line 19 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\SecurityListener::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController".
```

Any ideas?
Am I missing something?

Comment: > Inside SugarCrmConnect.php I have a class called SugarConnect --> in PSR-0 the classname must be equal to the filename.

Comment: Sorry, that was a Typo, the classname is SugarCrmConnect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I had to register my namespaces manually in autoload_classmap.php, located at vendor/composer/